# How to solve Whitelabel Error page Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, tomcat

I am a beginner in Springboot and trying to build a project but whenever I try to run the project as a java application I get a Whitelabel error.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
no transaction is in progress
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

here is my pom.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.generator.marksheet</groupId>
    <artifactId>Marksheet-Generator</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Marksheet-Generator</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        
        <maven-jar-plugin-version>3.8.1</maven-jar-plugin-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    

</project>
```

and my `application.properties`

```
# database init, supports mysql too
spring.sql.init.platform = mysql
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:db/schema-mysql.sql
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:db/data-mysql.sql

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MarksheetGen
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=admin123
spring.sql.init.mode=always

#spring.sql.init.mode=always

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# Web
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl


# Internationalization
#spring.messages.basename=messages/messages

# Actuator
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

# Logging
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
# logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
# logging.level.org.springframework.context.annotation=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.web.*=TRACE

# Maximum time static resources should be cached
spring.web.resources.cache.cachecontrol.max-age=12h

server.port = 8080
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class = org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

**MarksheetController.java**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/student")

public class MarksheetController {
    
    @Autowired
    private MarksheetService marksheetService;
    
    @GetMapping("/details/{rollnumber}")
    
    public Student showDetails(@PathVariable int rollnumber) throws Exception {
        
        Student student = marksheetService.getdetails(rollnumber);
        
        if (student == null) {
            throw new Exception("Student not found - " + student);
        }
        
        return student;
    }

}
```

I am trying to return student details on the webpage tried all possible solutions on the web but none worked

**Here is the complete fallback**

```
no transaction is in progress
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(SessionImpl.java:3397)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1354)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1349)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:113)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:95)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:97)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:916)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:727)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    at com.generator.marksheet.Marksheet.Generator.service.MarksheetServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c67ab94d.getdetails(<generated>)
    at com.generator.marksheet.Marksheet.Generator.rest.MarksheetController.showDetails(MarksheetController.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Here is my MarksheetService.java

```
package com.generator.marksheet.Marksheet.Generator.service;

import com.generator.marksheet.Marksheet.Generator.entity.Student;

public interface MarksheetService {
    
    public Student getdetails(int rollnumber);


}
```

and MarksheetServiceImpl.java

```
package com.generator.marksheet.Marksheet.Generator.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.generator.marksheet.Marksheet.Generator.dao.MarksheetDAO;
import com.generator.marksheet.Marksheet.Generator.entity.Student;

@Service

public class MarksheetServiceImpl implements MarksheetService{
    
    @Autowired
    private MarksheetDAO marksheetDAO;
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Student getdetails(int rollnumber) {
        
        return marksheetDAO.getdetails(rollnumber);
    
    }
}
```

MarksheetDAO.java

```
package com.generator.marksheet.Marksheet.Generator.dao;

import com.generator.marksheet.Marksheet.Generator.entity.Student;

public interface MarksheetDAO {
    
    public Student getdetails(int rollnumber);

}
```

MarksheetDAOImpl.java

```
package com.generator.marksheet.Marksheet.Generator.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.generator.marksheet.Marksheet.Generator.entity.Student;

@Repository
public class MarksheetDAOImpl implements MarksheetDAO {
    
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    @Override
    public Student getdetails(int rollnumber) {
    // get the current hibernate session
            Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
             
            // now retrieve/read from database using the primary key
            Student student = currentSession.get(Student.class, rollnumber);
            
            return student;
    }

}
```

Getting this in console

```
Hibernate: select student0_.roll as roll1_0_0_, student0_.first_name as first_na2_0_0_, student0_.last_name as last_nam3_0_0_ from studentinfo student0_ where student0_.roll=?
```

Comment: please provide your statcktrace

Comment: https://pastebin.com/tjmYmFDg here it is @ScaryWombat

Comment: Please add it to your question.

Comment: @ScaryWombat it's exceeding 30k limit :(

Comment: @ScaryWombat edited the post

Comment: so it is happening in `marksheetService.getdetails`  - please share this code.

Also you could would be better if you did a try...catch.. around your `marksheetService.getdetails` code and then printed the stacktrace.

Comment: @ScaryWombat please look at edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using Entitymanager provided by springboot
turns out if you want to use Sessionfactory then you need to define a config.java and provide properties for transaction management and Sessionfactory there.

Comment: Glad you have it fixed.  This answer may help others in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Put @Transactional on marksheet service class.

@Transactional
Public class MarksheetService {

}

Comment: already did didn't help